# 12.04 doesn't accept shutdown command

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, users, guest-session

When I try to shutdown my machine using the normal shutdown menu it just logs off the current user and brings me back to the lightdm login window.
I have to open a terminal and execute "shutdown -h now" to shutdown my system.
Any help?

EDIT: I noticed this behavior only occurs when I was previously switching users on my pc i.e. the 'guest-session' is still running in the background.

Comment: do you have RabbitMQ installed?

Comment: no. I don't have rabbitmq.

Comment: You can install RabbitMQ with "sudo apt-get install rabbitmq"

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the multiple logged in users in your system. I used to experience the same problem. Solved it by a policy chane allowing logout even when multiple users are logged in. If you understand the implications(like lose of non-saved data, for other logged in users) of allowing such a thing, you could go ahead and do the same.
It can be done as follows:

1. `sudo vi /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/usershutdown.pkla`
2. As content of that file, enter the following and save it:

   `[Allow Shutdown]`
   `Identity=unix-user:*`
   `Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop-multiple-users`
   `ResultAny=yes`
   `ResultInactive=yes`
   `ResultActive=yes`
   `[Allow Restart]`
   `Identity=unix-user:*`
   `Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart-multiple-users`
   `ResultAny=yes`
   `ResultInactive=yes`
   `ResultActive=yes`

Now restart your system and check if things are working as intended.

**N.B:** You could use any other editor of your choice to create that file.